# VBA: Check if one cell contains some value and how to copy/paste that value to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns: Column W and Column X.
In Column W, from Range W2 to W40, I want to check if that cell contains a value like "FedEx/DHL/TNT/UPS" and if the cell has that value, then that value should be pasted on the X column. The value can be case insensitive.

I expect the cell on the X column should have the value from the W column.

What I would like to see is that if the cell contains the value "FedEx/DHL/TNT/UPS" then it should mention in the next column the value. Can the value be checked based on the first or 2nd line? For Example, This is the value that I have in cell A2: FedEx Shipment 49XXXXXXXXXX I would like to have a VBA that says like if the FedEx is mentioned on that cell, then on the cell B2, it should be showing FedEx. Is there a way to do this in VBA??

Comment: Is VBA necessary as a simple if Formula will work?

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, using a formula may be the way to go, but here are the two options.

In a formula.  The false option here is empty.
 `=IF(W2="FedEx/DHL/TNT/UPS","FedEx/DHL/TNT/UPS","")`

And in VBA.  Notice there is no copy/paste.  Making the cells equal is more efficient.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub FindValuePaste()

    Dim FndRng As Range
    Dim cll As Range

    Set FndRng = Range("W2:W40")

    For Each cll In FndRng
        If cll.Value Like "*Fedex*" Or cll.Value Like "*DHL*" Or cll.Value Like "*UPS*" Or cll.Value Like "*TNT*" Then
            cll.Offset(0, 1) = cll.Value
        End If
    Next cll

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Darrell, I tried to use the formula that you sent, but that didn't work.
What I would like to see is that if the cell contains the value "Fedex/DHL/TNT/UPS" then it should mention on the next column the value. Can the value be checked based on the first or 2nd line?

For Example: This is the value that I have in cell A2: FedEx Shipment 49XXXXXXXXXX

I would like to have a VBA that says like if the FedEx is mentioned on that cell, then on the cell B2, it should be showing FedEx.

Is there a way to do this in VBA?

Comment: I have updated the VBA portion to your response.  Note the `Option Compare Text` above the `Sub`.  This ensures case insensitivity.